# Unable to boot from Mac OS X Snow Leopard DVD in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I downloaded Mac OS X Snow Leopard DVD from Apple Developer Connection website from [this](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Mac_OS_X/mac_os_x_version_10.6_snow_leopard_build_10a432/mac_os_x_v10.6_build_10a432_user_dvd.dmg) link. I am attempting to install it as a guest OS using Virtual Machine (version 5.2.10, current as of this writing) running on macOS High Sierra 10.13.4, running on a Late 2013 15" Retain MacBook Pro.

However after booting from the DVD, I am encountering this error:

[image]

Here is the machine configuration, boot order, memory:

[image]

[image]

What could possibly be causing this issue? Is there a way around this and install Mac OS X Snow Leopard in Virtual Box?

Comment: What are your settings for  the VirtualBox Machine (please include boot order, memory, etc.)? Also, may I suggest Parallels Desktop Lite from the App Store.  It is free and very similar to Virtual Box but does not have as many errors.  You may be able to run what you want hassle free.

Comment: @Josh Updated the question.

Comment: It will be really difficult to help without the Disk Image (I am not an Apple Developer) but I have had experience with similar issue in Virtual Box.  Some questions and a possible answer:  Have you followed a tutorial to set this up? If so, can you provide the link.  Have you selected Mac OS X 10.6 when creating the VM? Can you try unchecking Enable EFI and Hardware Clock? Can you add the disk under and IDE controller instead of a SATA controller?